# How to model 4 camera automatically in python

Tags: python, camera

```
import bpy
import numpy
import math
import os
from mathutils import Euler
from bpy import context, data, ops
    
scene = bpy.context.scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global = False, confirm = False)


#***********************Camera parameters**********************************
focal    = 3.04  #focal lenght (mm)
sw       = 3.68  #sensor width (mm)
sh       = 2.76  #sensor height (mm)
eul_mode ='XYZ'


number_cam = 4
count      = 1

location = [(0, 0, 3), (3, 0, 3), (0, 3, 3), (0, -3, 3)]
rotation = [(math.radians(0), math.radians(0), math.radians(0)), (math.radians(45), math.radians(0), math.radians(90)), (math.radians(45), math.radians(0), math.radians(180)), (math.radians(45), math.radians(0), math.radians(0))]

if count <= number_cam:
    for cam in scene.objects:
        cam_name = 'Camera' + str(count)
        cam      = bpy.data.cameras.new(name = cam_name)
        cam.lens = focal
        cam.sensor_width  = sw
        cam.sensor_height = sh

        cam_obj                = bpy.data.objects.new(cam_name, [cam + str(count)])
        cam_obj.rotation_mode  = eul_mode
        cam_obj.location       = location[count]
        cam_obj.rotation_euler = math.radians(rotation[count])
        scn.collection.objects.link(cam_obj)
        
count = count + 1
```

I am a beginner in python with Blender.

I would like to create 4 cameras automatically with Python but I have an error in this code.
Can you tell me what this error is and if what I want to do is possible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello, what are you trying to do ultimately ?

Comment: error is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text", line 11, in <module>
NameError: name 'scene' is not defined
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console ...you SHOULD copy all your code in here, not just parts. With the imports too...!

Comment: and if you would assign the scene variable correctly...the next error is: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text", line 16, in <module>
NameError: name 'focal' is not defined
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

....sorry, but you SHOULD watch/read some beginner python tutorials. You will not get any result without some basic knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
So, Gorgious, I'm trying to create 4 cameras with different locations and orientations. I want to have some automation because it's the same code all the time.

Chris, I'm sorry I didn't put in all the code. I'll keep that in mind. I hope now that it is OK for you! Also, I have already watched some python tutorials for beginners, otherwise I would never have written this code. Thanks again for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some fixes.**

- Lose the "bling" ... many moons ago a language named `COBOL` was
  nicely aligned on equals signs, would stick with pep8 for python. The
  result below is result of autopep8 via nvim text editor.
- Never a fan of scripts that delete everything first, took that out,
  it was an issue with your original logic, since the scene now had no
  objects.
- Made one loop to add each camera. Named via fstring formatting rather than string addition (which can be slow).

Resultant script.

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from bpy import context, data

scene = context.scene

#***********************Camera parameters************************
focal = 3.04  #focal lenght (mm)
sw = 3.68  #sensor width (mm)
sh = 2.76  #sensor height (mm)
eul_mode = 'XYZ'

number_cam = 4

location = [(0, 0, 3), (3, 0, 3), (0, 3, 3), (0, -3, 3)]
rotation = [(radians(0), radians(0), radians(0)),
            (radians(45), radians(0), radians(90)),
            (radians(45), radians(0), radians(180)),
            (radians(45), radians(0), radians(0))]

for count in range(number_cam):
   cam_name = f'Camera{count}'
   cam = bpy.data.cameras.new(name=cam_name)
   cam.lens = focal
   cam.sensor_width = sw
   cam.sensor_height = sh

   cam_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(cam_name, cam)
   cam_obj.rotation_mode = eul_mode
   cam_obj.location = location[count]
   cam_obj.rotation_euler = rotation[count]
   scene.collection.objects.link(cam_obj)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is what I was searching